# pg_repack not organizing table by column

Tags: postgresql

I'm using `pg_repack` to order one table by a timestamp column, however I'm finding that after running `pg_repack` command it's not ordered at all.

I'm using this command

```
pg_repack --jobs 4 -t table_with_dates -e -o "start_time asc"
```

After about 10 minutes it finishes but when I query the first page of the table there is no order over "start_time" column.

[image: page 0 rows]

I'm using postgresql 9.6.3 and pg_repack 1.4.0

Is there something i'm missing here so I can get the correct data ordering?

Edit 1:
**Table definition**

```
CREATE TABLE customer_service (
    customer_service_id character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    store_id character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    start_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    end_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    customer_id character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    service_id character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT customer_service_key PRIMARY KEY (customer_service_id),
);
CREATE INDEX customer_service_start_idx
  ON public.customer_service
  USING btree
  (start_time);

 CREATE INDEX customer_service_customer_idx
  ON public.customer_service
  USING btree(customer_id);

CREATE INDEX customer_service_service_idx
  ON public.customer_service
  USING btree
  (service_id);
```

`SELECT` **performed by** `pg_repack`:

```
LOG: (query) CREATE TABLE repack.table_6527203 WITH (oids = false) TABLESPACE pg_default AS SELECT customer_service_id, store_id, start_time, end_time, customer_id, service_id
FROM ONLY customer_service
ORDER BY start_time WITH NO DATA

LOG: (query) INSERT INTO repack.table_6527203 SELECT customer_service_id, store_id, start_time, end_time, customer_id, service_id
FROM ONLY customer_service
```

Seems like the insert into is not ordering the data?, as the order by is only present on the create table command

Edit 2:
If I run

```
WITH dates_per_page AS (
  SELECT (ctid::text::point)[0]::bigint AS page_number, COUNT(DISTINCT date(start_time))
  FROM customer_service
  GROUP BY 1
) SELECT avg(count) FROM dates_per_page;
```

I get 15.340 as the result, I would expect a number closer to 1 here...

Comment: Can you show us what's the `SELECT` you performed to retrieve the data? The data *might* be in order (at least in terms of *pages*), even if it doesn't look like it.

Comment: @joanolo the `ctid` shows these rows are in this physical order, doesn't it?

Comment: Could you please show the table definition (with indexes)?  No screenshot, normal text, please.

Comment: I can confirm the missing `ORDER BY` clause is the one to blame here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is fixed on the version 1.4.1 of pg_repack.

[github issue for reference](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/issues/138)